# Ruby += assignment operator

Tags: ruby

```
foo = [10,20,30,40,50,60]
foo_total = 0
foo.each do |f|
 print foo_total += f
end
print foo_total
```

The output of this code sample will be `10 30 60 100 150 210 210` but I'm actually looking for `10 20 30 40 50 60 210`
I know that it can be achieved by using the following code

```
foo = [10,20,30,40,50,60]
foo_total = 0
foo.each do |f|
 print f
 foo_total += f
end
print foo_total
```

However, is there a more elegant approach that needs just one line in the `foo.each` block?

edit: It's not only about the output, but also about having the variable foo_total that contains the sum of all values in foo

Comment: I suppose you could use an abomination like `print (foo_total += f) - f`.

Comment: `print f; foo_total +=f` would be one line, but not one statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do as below

```
(arup~>~)$ pry --simple-prompt
>> foo = [10,20,30,40,50,60]
=> [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]
>> foo.push(foo.inject(:+))
=> [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 210]
>>
```

Comment: Just to enhance, since OP seems to be looking for a string: `foo.join(' ')`

Comment: I doubt the OP wants a string. Using `print` will result in the values being output on a single line in the console, but nowhere is there an indication that the array should be joined or "stringified" in any way.

Comment: @theTinMan is right. I want to print each number in foo and also have the variable foo_total that contains the sum of all values in foo

Comment: My bad, sorry folks (I should not be commenting on SO on low sleep) :-)

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
foo.each do |f|
  foo_total += f.tap { |f1| print f1 }
end
```

Comment: +1 for anything with `tap`, though I doubt you'd use this just to save a line of code.  (I love the sound of that method. `tap.tap.tap` is even better.)